# Make text block wider in A4 page

Tags: margins

I'm struggling to fit a wider text into an A4 page. This page isn't going to be printed as a book, it is simply for internal use, so I don't mind if the text occupies more % of the page. I've tried different commands, to various effects, but nothing would change the width of the text stripe. The best I could get was to shift the entire block of text in either direction...

These are the commands I've tried:

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{500pt}
\hspace{-32pt}
%% \textwidth=490pt
%% \marginparwidth=-12pt
%% \marginparsep=-12pt
%% \marginparpush=-12pt
%% \oddsidemargin=-12pt
%% \hoffset=-12pt
```

and variations. The template used is `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`

Sorry, the choice of tags is somewhat arbitrary - I don't really know where my problem belongs. Feel free to change it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you try package [`a4wide`](http://ctan.org/pkg/a4wide):

```
\usepackage{a4wide}
```

For a similar problem I used

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[top=30pt,bottom=30pt,left=48pt,right=46pt]{geometry}
```

Comment: `a4wide` should not be used, as it introduces some incompatibilities with the LaTeX setup (it used to be a style option for LaTeX 2.09).

Comment: Sorry to be a prick, but setting up LaTeX is immensely convoluted - no wonder someone found him/herself incompatible :) Considering the effort it takes to install a package, some times, it's faster to put together pixels in GIMP or similar.

Comment: It's not convoluted if you use the geometry package, which comes preinstalled.

Answer (score 8):

Even though the question was already answered, for the sake of completeness, you could use the package `fullpage`:

```
\usepackage{fullpage}
```

and add the `cm` option for an even wider line length:

```
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
```

Answer (score 5):

An exaggerated version:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum} % <- For dummy text

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{500pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Also, if you want to see how the document layout parameters work you can use the following for reference.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it too does the job, the one suggested by Bruno was just simpler :)

Answer (score 5):

If want a wider text block, but still a traditionally well-calculated and well-positioned text block, you could use the `typearea` package from the KOMA-Script bundle, which you can use with your normal `article` document class. It has an option `DIV`, which is used to calculate the type area. The greater the value of `DIV`, the wider the text block becomes. If you want `typearea` to find a value based on the page size, say `DIV=calc`.

```
\usepackage[DIV=11]{typearea}
```

Here's a table from the [KOMA-Script Guide](http://texdoc.net/pkg/typearea) (p. 23) showing some text block widths for A4 paper:

[image: Type-area dimensions dependent on DIV for A4]

If you want to learn something about such page geometry calculation, section 2.5. *Options and Macros to Influence the Page Layout* (p. 21–34) of that guide would be a good read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is interesting, too. But I'd have to allocate some weekend to learning how to install LaTeX packages. Last time I tried I gave up somewhere in the middle of step 3.

Comment: for me, this is the preferred way to change the page layout

Answer (score 4):

Why didn't you use the geometry package ?

```
\usepackage[left=0.50cm, right=0.50cm, top=0.50cm, bottom=0.50cm]{geometry}
```

And you can change the 0.50cm with the margin you want. If all the margins are the same it is shorter to write:

```
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: Because there is an excessive amount of settings and ways to do the same thing... I was 2 steps before trying this approach once you suggested it.

Comment: If you set all margins to the same value, you can also just say `\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}`. (Feel free to edit this information into your answer)

Comment: Thanks @doncherry I didn't know this information before, but I think it's more personalizable the way it is, don't you agree ? cuz not all margins must be the same, you can choose any value you want.