# Disable binding compensation for titlepage

Tags: margins, titles, koma-script

How do you disable the binding compensation in KOMAscript (e.g. `\documentclass[BCOR10mm]{scrbook}`) on the titlepage? I use the `titlepage` package and the `fullsizetitle` environment, but this is not enough to remove binding compensation.

That said, I realize that are are settings in which you still want to have binding compensation, even on the titlepage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\KOMAoptions{BCOR=0mm}` at a given point, and then revert it back to whatever value you want after `\maketitle`.

<sup>Be aware that `typearea` will complain, calling it a “dirty hack”.</sup>

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}% to create dummy text with \blindtext, \Blinddocumet
\usepackage{showframe}% to print the typearea as a frame
\title{Title}
\author{A.\,Uthor}
\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{BCOR=0mm}
\maketitle
\KOMAoptions{BCOR=20mm}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

See also:

- [Remove margins for title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20177/5872)
- [KOMA-Script unequal left/right margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85884/5872)
- [Overview of Margins in KOMA Script/TypeArea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51396/5872) (to see the layout in detail, in case you need)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Though, `typearea` yields some warnings now, but I think I can live with them - especially as I know that using two different documents and combining them afterwards would be the cleaner solution.